# How do you call functions that fulfill $f(x)=\pm f(\pm 1/x)$?

Tags: functions, terminology, graphing-functions, symmetry

A function $f(x)$ that fulfills $f(x)=\pm f(-x)$ is called <strike>(a)symmetric</strike> even/odd.

> How do you call functions that fulfill $f(x)=\color{blue}\pm f(\color{red}\pm 1/x)$?

"$\color{red}{\text{Positive/Negative}}$ Reciprocal $\color{blue}{\text{(anti)symmetric}}$"..?

*edited according to the comments...*

Comment: Usually a function satisfying $f(x) = \pm f(-x)$ is called even or odd, not (a)symmetric.  Maybe (anti)symmetric with respect to $x \to -x$.  Certainly it should be (anti) rather than (a), because "asymmetric" just means "not symmetric".
And then if $s$ is an involution, you can call a function satisfying $f(x) = \pm f(s(x))$ (anti)symmetric with respect to the involution $s$.

Comment: If you only consider $f(x)=\pm f(1/x)$ on $\mathbb R^+$, then $g=f\circ\exp$ is even/odd. Equivalently, $f$ is the composition of an even/odd function and the logarithm function...

Comment: '-1', I did not find your question useful to me.

Comment: @user31782 when you think I downvoted your other question, you are wrong. I upvoted your answer instead. Very sad that you feel the need for revenge. Where is the love...

Comment: Hi @draks... the downvote is not due to revenge. Let's talk about this on meta: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/13921/103816

Comment: @user31782 because of this downvote- issue you decide to leave Math.SE? Come on, don't take it that personally, this is the internet! I don't think you'll find a better math resource somewhere...BTW:Thanks for revoking your downvote

Comment: @draks... My friend, there is a thing called dignity.I always tried to be specific and on-topic in any discussion on meta. I did not participate on MSE as a result of my suspension on Phys.SE. I did participate here because I want to learn Math. But my recent posts were downvoted and closed unjustifiably. When I downvoted others posts for the same reason they downvoted mine then they don't like me.I  always wanted to be a part of scientific community.I don't want to be a part of political community.I have a tiny knowledge of Math.I don't thinkmy resign will make any problems toyou&others,Rgrds